# C# editorconfig - How specify rules depending on the inheritance

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editorconfig

I'm studding how can I "normalize" code by using the editorconfig with Visual Studio, and what I want to know is, how can I create a naming rule depending of what inheritance a object has.

In this example, I want to maintain the default naming pattern, but if some specific inheritance happens, demand that an underline prefix is used.

Like:

```
public class GeneratorModule() //ok
public class generatorModule() //wrong

public class GeneratorModule() : Module //wrong
public class _GeneratorModule() : Module //ok
```

I looked a lot of documentations, but nothing that helps in this case, any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Based on my current test, I could not find a way to specify rules depending on the inheritance. Because there is no specific keyword to show the Inheritance. You could refer to the link[Code-style naming rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/naming-rules?view=vs-2019#example) to know it.

Comment: There was where I study, but maybe an extension could do it...... Thank you for your time.